# Php 8 error Cannot use positional argument after named argument

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index(){

 $products = Product::all();

return view(view:'admin.products.index', compact(varname: 'products'));

}
```

the aim of this function is to retrieve data from my database and display on the page im running it on but i keep getting the error i mentioned in the title

Answer (score 3):

The problem is self explanatory:

```
return view(view:'admin.products.index', compact(var_name: 'products'));
```

Here you used named argument `view` and then followed it by an argument without a name i.e. a positional argument. You need to change this to:

```
return view(view:'admin.products.index', data: compact(var_name: 'products'));
```

As @Repox mentioned the name of the parameter in `compact` is `var_name` as well

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling in the parameter name for the [compact function](https://php.net/compact). It should be `var_name` and not `varname`.

```php
public function index() {

    $products = Product::all();

    return view(view:'admin.products.index', compact(var_name: 'products'));

}
```

Comment: @Repox.Thanks for pointing,i didnt knew it changed :)

Comment: @Repox  i made that change but still ended up with the same error

Comment: @G-guy Of course, that's because you are having a positioned argument in `view()` after a named argument. See @apokryfos answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can be written more simple like

```
return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'));
```

compact ( array|string $var_name , array|string ...$var_names ) : array

https://www.php.net/compact

Comment: typed it exactly as you put there and still ended up with same error

Comment: Sorry I dd not see your view: , answer updated, see @apkryfos answer that's the best explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Product::all();

return view(view: 'admin.products.index',data: compact('products'));
```

This code is working on my PC. If you are using PHPStorm, make sure that view, data, compact is generating automatically for you. Don't copy and paste - it may not work.